# Material UI inline styling - specific component colours

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm trying to style my TextFields from Material-UI. I have a black background and I need both the textField border and text to be white. Here's my (relevant) code:

```
render() {
    const styles = {
      width: {
        width: '90%',
        margin: '5px',
        padding: '5px',
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        hintColor: '#ffffff',
        floatingLabelColor: '#ffffff',
        disabledTextColor: '#673ab7',
        focusColor: '#c2185b',
        borderColor: '#ffffff'
      },
      button: {
        margin: '15px',
        padding: '20px',
        width: '60%'
      }
    };

<TextField
              className="classes.textField"
              label="Name Your Vice"
              type="text"
              name="vice"
              value={this.props.vice}
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              style={styles.width}
              onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
            />
```

What am I missing to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: What renders with this code? What doesn’t match with what you were expecting.

Comment: where is `return`

Comment: This renders a textfield that has primary styling based on Material-UI's standard theme. Return isn't there because I didn't want to paste all my code as it's irrelevant to the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

TextField is an abstraction of several other components. from the [documentation:](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

> Advanced Configuration
>
> It's important to understand that the text field is a simple
>   abstraction on top of the following components:
>
> - FormControl
> - InputLabel
> - List item
> - Input
> - FormHelperText

Some of the stylings you are trying to do apply to the `Input`.

So your code should look a bit like this:

```
const styles = {
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
}

< TextField InputProps = {{ style: styles.input }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that Material UI required a lot of digging down into the components to make very basic changes. I instead used Materialize (a more friendly version of Material UI) and found it relatively simple to customise my components.

Answer (score 0):

To set the border and background color with TextField variant "outlined" you need to target the fieldset.

You can do something like this:

```
const styles = {
  textField: {
    [`& fieldset`]: {
      border:"1px solid #fff",
      backgroundColor: "#fff"
    }
};
```